# content url is not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

My CSS file is:

```
        #name_wrong_img
        {
           width:43px;
           height:29px;
        }
```

This is my HTML code:

```
         <img id="name_wrong_img" src="wrong.jpg" />
```

The above code is working well in both Firefox and Chrome.

```
        #name_wrong_img
        {
           content:url(wrong.jpg);
           width:43px;
           height:29px;
        } 

         <img id="name_wrong_img"  />
```

This is working well in Chrome. But not in Firefox. What is the problem in this?

Comment: if you want to show wrong.jpg in name_wrong_img then you can use background:url;

Comment: not working in firefox means, not showing the image

Comment: I am using Internal(embedded) stylesheet.

Comment: if you give image in CSS then there is no need to give IMG tag

Comment: background:url also not working. give some other ideas.

Comment: This question should not have been closed.  It is a valid question, clear to me what was asked, because I had the same question, and there is a clear and accepted answer below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support the `content` property in the same way as Chrome — on `img` elements and/or when the source is an image.

`<img>` represents a content image. If you use it, it should have a `src` and an `alt`.

From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-img-element.html#the-img-element):

> The src attribute must be present, and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted.

Comment: You don't. If it is a content image you use an `<img>` element and set its src in the HTML.

Comment: But that's so much less useful than what Chrome does.  Especially when you've got third-party libraries that rely on `content` to display images.  Why can't Firefox mimic Chrome in this case?

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17907900/213902