# CSS image replacement for Firefox

Tags: html, css, image-replacement

Hi I am using the following code to replace an image on my website using CSS:

```
img[src*="marker.png"]{ content: url("golfball2.png"); }
```

This code is good for safari and chrome. I am just wondering does anyone know any pieces of code I could use to do the same job in Firefox?

Comment: Try `img[src*="marker.png"]:after{ content: url("golfball2.png"); }`

Comment: No that didnt work :( made the image stay even in safari.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12262175/1763929).