# Content url does not display image on firefox browser

Tags: css, firefox

```
.googlePic{
    content: url('../../img/googlePlusIcon.PNG');
    margin-top: -6.5%;
    padding-right: 53px;
    float:right;
    height: 19px;

}
```

This is an example of my class `googlePic` in my `css` file. It works out and prints out nicely on `google chrome` and `safari`. however, it doesn't work on `firefox`. `Nth` gets printed out. Please help :)

Comment: I don't think you can use 'content' that way. Use 'background' instead.

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262118/content-url-is-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: adding alt in <img> worked for me
<img class="rounded-circle step1-img" alt="step1-img" />

Answer (score 30):

The `content` property works with `::before` and `::after`.

```
googlePic::before
{
 content: url('../../img/googlePlusIcon.PNG');
}
```

Read this:
http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/content/

IE8 only supports the `content` property if a !DOCTYPE is specified.

Comment: In Firefox, :before did not work for me, but :after did, as reported by Ahetesum Ali

Answer (score 22):

I know this may be a late response, but i came across the same problem.

I looked it up and somehow an url is not a valid 'content' type and even tho Chrome and Safari are being the good guys and show it nicely.

What worked for me, was creating an empty 'content' and using a background to show the image:
it works nicely in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE8+9

```
.googlePic:before {
    content: '';
    background: url('../../img/googlePlusIcon.PNG');
    margin-top: -6.5%;
    padding-right: 53px;
    float:right;
    height: 19px;
}
```

edit: forgot to put the :before after the classname

Comment: This is the solution and should be marked as the answer. For some reason some browsers don't accept url as content.

Comment: Is there anything else to try after this does not work?

Answer (score 16):

you have to write two css class in style

```
.googlePic
{  /*this for crome browser*/
    content: url('../../img/googlePlusIcon.PNG');
    margin-top: -6.5%;
    padding-right: 53px;
    float:right;
    height: 19px;

}

.googlePic: after
{  /*this for firefox browser*/
    content: url('../../img/googlePlusIcon.PNG');
    margin-top: -6.5%;
    padding-right: 53px;
    float:right;
    height: 19px;

}
```

and its works for me :)

Comment: Nothing for me. Firefox and IE - no reaction

Comment: In my case :after pseudo element gets Firefox to render, but not :before

Comment: i am not a expart in css just found the above  answer later changes the before to after it worked

Comment: Is there anything else to try after this does not work?

Comment: The after works for me. Be careful, remove the space between : after


`.googlePic:after
{  /*this for firefox browser*/
    content: url('../../img/googlePlusIcon.PNG');
    margin-top: -6.5%;
    padding-right: 53px;
    float:right;
    height: 19px;

}`

Comment: It didn't work like that for me either. I managed with `#image { content: ''; background-image: url("../../img/googlePlusIcon.png") !important; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 33vw; width: 100%;}`

Answer (score 6):

The best way to handle images throughout all web browsers is to use the background css property with the background-size.
However, IE8 and lower version won't support it [(represent 2% of viewer in 2014)](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp)

```
.googlePic{
    background: url('../../img/googlePlusIcon.PNG') -6.5% 53px no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    float:right;
    height: 19px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I simply added 'alt' and it was working with without using Pseudo classes

Comment: Wow! That's crazy. This fixed it for me too. I'm in awe that the solution is this simple. Great eye.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the tag to a div and not a img , content should work in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This saved me. Remember to remove `alt` attribute from the `img` or you will find the `alt` and the actual image in Firefox.

```
   .googlePic, .googlePic:after{
        content: url('../../img/googlePlusIcon.PNG');
        margin-top: -6.5%;
        padding-right: 53px;
        float:right;
        height: 19px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `alt` attribute to the `img` tag and then using `content="url('...')"` will work in firefox. For e.g.:

```
<img class="my-image" alt="myImage" />

.my-image {
  content: url("...");
  width: 10px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Doing this causes the image to look larger in Chrome for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently and none of the solutions above worked for me. I have resorted to the following work-around.

I included Bootstrap in my projects and used its [img-responsive](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp) class.
After that, I simply include the image using the `<img class="img-responsive">` tag. It displays and scales beautifully on every browser and every viewport size.

Hopefully this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, in my case I was not able to show the image using `content:url()`. I wanted to display waiting gif in one div. I don't know the details of Mozilla support. But it is resolved in my case by the following code.

```css
.img_div{
    background-image: url("wait.gif");
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-size: contain;
    border: none;
}
```

It is working on Chrome 73 and Firefox 66.

Answer (score -1):

worked for me this way.had to put file/// and then url.
        file///C:/user/s/desktop.......jpg

Comment: background-image: url(file///C:/user/s/desktop.......jpg)

Answer (score -4):

You can experiment with setting height and width to 0, add a padding and set the background image. You will have to make it display: block or display: inline-block for the height to take effect.

Here is an example:  [http://jsfiddle.net/zBgHd/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/zBgHd/1/)

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.