# content:url(); isnt displaying my image in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm not sure why this isn't working but in Firefox I have noticed that my image in content:url() isn't being displayed.

It is displayed in opera, chrome and safari but not Firefox.

Can anyone tell me why? I found a similar question on the stack forum but I don't understand if the problem was resolved.

[similar question on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser)

I also read online that pseudo elements cant be absolutely positioned for Firefox 3.something? I'm running on Firefox 27.0.1 and would have thought it wouldn't cause a problem.

Here is my css:

```
.arrow_box_recovery:after {
  content: url("http://dev.disklabs.com/html/assets/img/menu-arrow-recovery.png") no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have "no-repeat" after the url. remove it, and it will work, like this:

```
.arrow_box_recovery:after {
  content: url("http://dev.disklabs.com/html/assets/img/menu-arrow-recovery.png");
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I cant believe it was something so small, silly me!

Comment: @DuddiMai I delted my answer as this user already answered the same, so will upvote this :)

Comment: @fnk Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you by clicking on the tick besides the answer on the left side