# Firefox does not show the logo while Chrome does

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following css:

```
 #logo{
    content: url(../images/logo.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  #logo-container{
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 65px;
    width: 100px;
  }
```

with that html:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-3 ">
                <div id="logo-container"><a id="logo" href="#firstpage" data-target="start" title="EPIC Companies"></a></div>  
            </div>
```

Chrome shows the logo correctly, while the Firefox show a black rectangle (only the container). What I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Content url does not display image on firefox browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser)

Comment: use :after in #logo it creates a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content` can only be used in pseudo-elements like `:after` or `:before`.

So use it this way:

```css
#logo:after {
    content: url(../images/logo.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has limited support for the `content` attribute, specifically, it can't be used with images.

You'll probably have to use an `<img>` tag.

EDIT: According to the linked duplicate question, it looks like it actually will work in Firefox if you  use it with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-attributes.

Comment: are you sure about that? have a read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: It's been my experience at least. I've tried using `content` in Firefox before and I can't get it to work with images.