# jqGrid image in a column not working in firefox

Tags: css, image, firefox, jqgrid

Good morning all,

I have to show a 16x40 pixel image in a jqGrid column, that changes when I click
on it; at this purpose, I defined my formatter as follow:

```
function dataViewLink(cellValue, options, rowdata, action)
{   
    var chartLink = "<div style='float:left;'><img id='_addtochart" + options.rowId + "' class='ui-icon-addtochart' onclick='devToggleChartChecked("  + options.rowId + ")'></img></div>";
    return chartLink; 
}
```

and created two CSS classes with different images:

```
.ui-icon-addtochart
{
    content: url(../images/addtochart.jpg) !important;
}

.ui-icon-removefromchart
{
    content: url(../images/removefromchart.jpg) !important;
}
```

then, I dynamically switch these classes using jquery. Everything
works fine on chrome, but there is no way to get it working on firefox.
The images does not show on firefox.

I have already found an issue related to the 'content' attribute on firefox:

[Content url does not display image on firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser)

and tried all the suggested workarounds, but none of them worked for me.

I cannot show these images with firefox.

This little problem is driving me crazy. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thank you very much in advanced.

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a solution; I changed my formatter with:

```
function dataViewLink2(cellValue, options, rowdata, action)
{   
    var chartLink = "<div style='float:left;' id='_addtochart" + options.rowId + "' class='ui-icon-addtochart ui_add_dev' onclick='devToggleChartChecked("  + options.rowId + ")'></div>";
    return chartLink; 
}
```

and the CSS classes:

```
.ui-icon-addtochart
{
    background: url(../images/addtochart.jpg);
    height: 16px;
    width: 144px;
}

.ui-icon-removefromchart
{
    background: url(../images/removefromchart.jpg);
    height: 16px;
    width: 215px;
}
```

it works both on chrome and on firefox.

Thank you very much anyway!

Bruno