# Images appear on chrome, but not on firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Images appear fine on Chrome and Safari, but they don't appear on Firefox! would appreciate help

Here's my code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="clearearlanding"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
div.clearearlanding {
  content: url('/images/clearearlandingpage.png');
  margin-left: -70px;
  width: 120%;
}
```

Comment: which versions are you using? mention please on your question. That will be helpful to give answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content url does not display image on firefox browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser)

Comment: This was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser)

Answer (score 1):

`content` is only supposed to be used on pseudo-elements (`:before` and `:after`).

> It can only be used with the pseudo elements :after and :before.
>   (According to [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/))

Somehow, it works on normal elements too, but only in WebKit-Browsers like Chrome and Safari, as you noticed.

> But only works on webkit browsers like chrome and safari.
>   (According to [George Nava on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/#li-comment-79856))

---

### Solutions

Some simple solutions:

Use `:before`:

**CSS:**

```
div.clearearlanding:before {
  content: url('/images/clearearlandingpage.png');
  margin-left: -70px;
  width: 120%;
}
```

---

Use an `img` tag (although you probably had your reasons to not use that):

**CSS:**

```
div.clearearlanding > img {
  margin-left: -70px;
  width: 120%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="clearearlanding">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=48&txt=512%C3%97256&w=512&h=256" />
</div>
```

---

Or use `background-image` on either `.clearearlanding` or its `:before` element.