# "Content" CSS code won't display image on firefox/IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I've already tried to fix the problem by following this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser#_=_)

But the "width" CSS code won't work properly, no idea why.
This is my code which works great on google chrome:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .why35 {
    content:url('image.png');
    width:178px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom:-7px;
  }
}
```

I've been trying to fix it for quite some time now but it just wont work, no clue why...

Any help? I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: As the question you have linked states, `content`only works in `:before` and `:after`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content url does not display image on firefox browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser)

Comment: Note what @FabianBettag mentions in his comment. Alternate method would be to use the [background-image property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)