# Set the equivalent of a src attribute of an img tag

Tags: html, css

I am doing like this:

```
<img class="myimg" />
.myimg{
    content:url('/images/user_logo.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

But the image is not getting displayed. I want to achieve it without using background image

Comment: Make sure you're targeting the correct class, so `.myimg` instead of `.mgimg`. Also, is there a reason why you want to add the image that way? Why not `<img src="/images/user_logo.png">` (update to have the correct path) and then style it with CSS to center how you want it?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost good, keep only the url *(but this is not supported by all the browser)*

```css
.myimg {
  content: url('https://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
}
```

```html
<img class="myimg">
```

This will also work if there is already an image defined:

```css
.myimg {
  content: url('https://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
}
```

```html
<img class="myimg" src="https://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/">
```

---

For browser compatibility better rely on another method. Let's assume that your image is within a container then you can try something like this:

```css
.myimg img {
  display: none;
}

.myimg:before {
  content: url('https://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
}
```

```html
<span class="myimg">
<img  src="https://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-image` for that:

```
.myimg{
 background-image: url('/images/user_logo.png');
}
```

Comment: I want it without using background-image

Answer (score -1):

Try using `:before` and `:after` method to achieve this. follow by the stack example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser)

```
.myimg:before {
    content:url('../images/user_logo.png');
}
```