# CSS - @media screen and (max-width: ---px) not working on firefox mobile

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries, width, screen

I want to replace the logo in the header of a website when it is is viewed on a mobile screen (screen width less than 500px). So I wrote the following CSS

`@media only screen and (max-width: 500px)  {.logo img{ content:url("....."); }}`

It's working fine on chrome but not on firefox.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Firefox has very good developer tools. Have you tried inspecting your page with them? Does everything look correct there? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure you have this meta in the  of your website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Secondly, try to use this

```
@media(max-width:500px){
/*Here your code*/
;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content property works with `::before` and `::after`.

Check this stackoverflow question for detialed information: [Content url does not display image on firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have managed to resolve the problem in a different way.
Instead of replacing the logo with a different one using the `content` command (which apparently gives problems in firefox), I kept the same logo and set the maximum width with `max-width` command using `vw` as a unit.

So this is how it looks like in the end.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.logo img{
max-width: 70vw;}
}
```

It seems to work fine both on chrome and firefox.