# replace content of img via css

Tags: html, image, css

I have this image tag:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
```

I need to replace the image via css (because I can't edit the html),so I use this css:

```
img {
 content: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200');
}
```

it's working well on chrome but not working in firefox and ie,any idea why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [content url is not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262118/content-url-is-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: this is example,in my code I write the .jpg

Comment: @user2232273 the src is fine

Comment: If you can't edit the html.. How do you let HTML know about your css?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we specify src attribute of img tag in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css)

Answer (score 9):

1) Set width and height of your image to 0.

2) Add a padding of 100px.

3) Add your new image via a background image

```
img {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200) no-repeat; /* <--- */
  width: 0; /* <--- */
  height: 0; /* <--- */
  padding: 100px; /* <--- */
}
```

```css
.replace {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200) no-repeat;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Image from placehold.it:</h4>

<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>

<hr>

<h4>Same image in markup - but replaced via CSS</h4>

<img class="replace" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ADkKW/4/)**

### How does this work?

Well, lets say we added padding to your original img element:

```
img {
    padding:100px;
    background: pink;
}
```

The result is your original img with 100px of pink background on each side

[image]

Now set width/height to 0:

```
img {
   padding:100px;
   background: pink;
   width:0;height:0;
}
```

You get a 200px X 200px pink area: (So now you've eliminated your original image)

[image]

Now change the pink background to your new background

```
background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200) no-repeat;
```

and you're done.

Comment: Wow, very nice trick. You may set only `width` (but not `height`) to `0` and set padding to `0 50%`. Then it will work for any image size.

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200) no-repeat;
  width: 200px; /* Width of new image */
  height: 200px; /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 200px; /* Equal to width of new image */
  }
```

Comment: i think it is the copy of the previous answer