# Is there a way to apply background color on <img> tag?

Tags: jquery, css, html

Is there a way to apply background color on `<img>` tag ?

```
<img src="abc.jpg" style="background-color:red;">
```

Above code is not working .

Please help me .

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you are using a jpg. You have to use an image with transparency.

Comment: wrap img tag in a div tag and apply background color on div tag.

Comment: @AT-2017 , i am using slick slider , and need to apply background color on selected thumbnail image .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make use of the [background-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode) property.

In particular, the `background-blend-mode: multiply` seems to be what you need here.

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blendingmultiply):

> **multiply blend mode**
>
> The source color is multiplied by the destination color and replaces
>   the destination.

```css
.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/200/150/animals);
}

.blended {
  background-color: red;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image blended"></div>
```

**NB:**

As you can't change your markup, there is still a way to style the images in the above way. (although it's a little bit hacky)

We can replace the img with the same background image with css by adding padding to the image and then setting the width and height of the image to zero. (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18483131/703717))

```css
img {
  padding: 75px 100px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-color: red;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/200/150/animals);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/animals">
```

Comment: I can not change my `html` code as it is generating  through the script

Comment: I updated the post with a css solution which might be viable for you.

Comment: User asked to apply background color on <img> tag not on some other element having background-image. So how come this is an answer?

Comment: @anu - see the second code snippet - the markup only contains an `img` tag - just like in the question.

Answer (score 13):

Yes it's possible. You just need to apply padding to image. Then you can get the result below:

or

You also can use .png images and apply transparent property.

```css
img {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/mario/mario_PNG53.png" style="background-color:red;padding:20px;">
```

Comment: NO , i want to cover whole image with background color

Comment: I can't change image type because there are so many products approximate 50000 having many jpg images

Answer (score 2):

Since you use Slick slider, you might want to do something like the example below. As noticed before, you also might want to use PNG instead of JPG since PNG has the support of transparency.

```
.slick-slide .image img {
   background-color: red;
   padding: 5px; //some padding to show the background color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<img class="image"/>
<img class="image blended"/>` change the div tag to image tag like