# Replace image with another image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hide

A piece of software we have uses a third party vendor to handle the validation errors. We are updating the UI at the moment and want to replace the image currently displayed with our own custom image.

I am able to target the image using CSS however the current image is still displaying over the new image.

Heres my HTML

```
<td >
<img src="warning.gif" border="0">
</td>
```

My CSS

```
td img {
    background-image: url("required.png")!important;
}
```

How can I hide the existing image and show my image just using CSS

Comment: Why not simply change the imagesource in the html code?

Comment: this works with CSS -> `content: url("required.png")`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `content:url("required.png")`

full CSS code:

```
td img {
    content: url("required.png");
}
```

Comment: this code have issue: it doesn't work in FF and IE -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262118/content-url-is-not-working-in-firefox and you need to use pseudoelements instead! Check @j08691 comment, it must work fine!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="header">
    <img class="banner" src="//notrealdomain1.com/banner.png">
</div>

/* All in one selector */
.banner {
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(http://notrealdomain2.com/newbanner.png) no-repeat;
    width: 180px; /* Width of new image */
    height: 236px; /* Height of new image */
    padding-left: 180px; /* Equal to width of new image */
}
```

Source + extra explanation:
[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:after` pseudo-element:

```css
td:hover::after {
    content:url(http://placehold.it/350x150/888/333);
}
td:hover > img {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/333/888" border="0">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```